# Best way to implement Jobs and applicants

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections

I am trying to implement a job board type application and wondering what is the best way to implement a "applicant" feature.

A job posting has zero to many applicants.  An applicant is a logged in user.  Once a user applies for a job, he/she can un-submit and cannot resubmit.

What is the best way to implement this?  Should I have a separate applicant model which has a user_id and status and corresponding views and controls?

Or should I just have a collection of "applicants" which stores user_ids and retrieve the name of the applicant through the user id?

Is there an implementation that I can see?

Thanks

Suni;

Answer (score 0):

I think that a new applicant model is redundant. A job has many users through job_applications is the best way to go in my opinion.

job_applications(job_id, user_id)